Removing 2nd switch from 2 way light
I got 2 way light in hallway (Australia). I want to keep single gang light switch working and close it on triple gang switch. What do I need to do to achieve that?



At both ends, disconnect the white wire and cap it off.
At the location where you don't want the switch anymore, connect the two red wires that are going to the switch together.
